# Will an AlertDialog have a resource ID if it isn't assigned one?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to Android and having issues with getting a view associated with a dialog box. If I create a dialog box like such:

```
AlertDialog.Builder adbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
adbuilder.SetTitle("Hello!");
adbuilder.SetNegativeButton("No", clickedNo);
adbuilder.SetPositiveButton("Yes", clickedYes);

AlertDialog ad = adbuilder.Create();
ad.Show();
```

My question, would this dialog box be accessible in any way? I want to use findviewbyID on it, does this even get assigned an ID? I know you can add a resource ID to it and such, but I want to see if there's a way around it. I'm trying to get the view of that dialog box. There's the method `GetIdentifier`, but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not shure if you can access the AlertDialog Negative/PositiveButton but you can use the  AlertDialog content area like this

```
AlertDialog.Builder adbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
adbuilder.SetTitle("Hello!");
adbuilder.SetNegativeButton("No", clickedNo);
adbuilder.SetPositiveButton("Yes", clickedYes);

View v = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.rz_promo_dialog, null);

v.findViewById(R.id.rz_dlg_img).setOnClickListener(...);    

alert.setView(v);

AlertDialog ad = adbuilder.Create();
ad.Show();
```

[update]
Sorry i just saw that this is a c#/xamarin question. My code is java but there shouldbe something similar in c#/xamarin

Comment: This would require assigning a resource ID in an xml file though correct? I might end up doing that, I just wanted to see if there was a simple workaround for the time being.